# Custom Cell button Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My scenario is as follow's:

Custom Cell View

[image]

1) I am populating data from server in the custom cell view which is perfectly populated, i want a link store in my array which i want to open in browser, so i want to check which index.row button is clicked so that against that row i can get the url link and open it in browser, so far i have found the solution of button tags but that doesn't work's as well, as if we have two cell's in the screen at same time on click of button both button return's same tag.

2) As the image attached i have another storyboard in which i want to segue to a new view controller, same as mentioned above, i want to pass a specific post title and key as well.

I hope every thing is clear.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: show some code how you have assign button tag?

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani cell.PostsButton.tag = indexPath.row; It's custom cell

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani 
On button click...
- (IBAction)Custombuttonclick:(id)sender {

    int tagid = (int)cell.PostsButton.tag;
    
    NSLog(@"%d",tagid);


    
}

Comment: I suggest using a delegation pattern.  Here is a similar answer I wrote in Swift; adapting to objective C is pretty straight-forward

Comment: @Paulw11 link to your answer?

Comment: Doh! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093596/how-to-get-the-indexpath-of-a-custom-table-view-cell-when-an-uiimage-inside-of-i/33093864#33093864

Comment: Another answer for you reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733924/

Comment: you want only index of that button that on which index the button was there in the tableview right?

Comment: see the @beyowulf's answer

Comment: @Jaimish that answer not work's as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found the solution of button tags but that doesn't work's as well**

Perform following steps to detect which button is selected.

1. Type the code snippet given below in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       // DEFINE CELL
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       // SET ACTION METHOD ON CALL BUTTON
       UIButton *button = (UIButton *) [self.view viewWithTag:40];

       [button setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

       [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];

   }
   ```
2. Add following method for `checkButtonTapped:`.

   ```
   - (void)checkButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
   {
       // GET POINT OF THE BUTTON PRESSED
       CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];

       // GET INDEXPATH FOR THE CELL WHERE THE BUTTON IS PRESSED
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

       if (indexPath != nil)
       {
           //Use indxPath.row to get item
           //Perform operations
       }
   }
   ```

There is another approach if you want to perform action according to the cell selected by the user.

**For the case where you want to check which row of the cell is clicked you should use following method.**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSLog(@"ShowindexPath%ld", (long)indexPath.row); }
```

Here we check for the user interaction on cell. `indexPath.row` will return `index` number for the cell selected by user. You can perform other actions in place of `NSLog` method.

**For the purpose to send value while performing segue use following steps:**

- Create property in the `NewViewController.h` file where you want to perform segue as follow:

  ```
  @property (nonatomic) NSString* receivedValue;
  ```
- `@synthesize` property by writing following code in `NewViewController.m` file within `@implementation` and `@end`

  ```
  @synthesize receivedValue;
  ```
- Import`NewViewController.h` file in `TableViewController.m` file.
- Go to `prepareForSegue:` method in the `TableViewController.m` file from where you want to send the value and write following code according to your class names within it.

  ```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  NewViewController *nVC = [segue destinationViewController];
  [nVC setReceivedValue:sendValue];
  }
  ```

Here `sendValue` is the value that you want to send.

That's all.
Build and run your project and enjoy.

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSLog(@"ShowindexPath%@", indexPath); return's (nul)l

Comment: It's on a button click

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience. I have changed the code which will give you the index for the selected cell. This code is 100% working.

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath will be called when we click on table view cell, in my case i want to click on button

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of your question. Tags are a pain. It's better to pass along the UIButton as the sender, and, in the action for the button, then you can say something like:

```
-(void) buttonPresse:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGPoint location = [self.tableView convertPoint:sender.bounds.origin fromView:sender];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath];
    //Do what you want with the cell or indexPath

}
```

Comment: an it's giving me an error:
Property 'bounds' not found on object of type '__strong id'

`- (IBAction)Custombuttonclick:(id)sender {
    
    CGPoint location = [tableviewcustom convertPoint:sender.bounds.origin fromView:sender];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableviewcustom indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableviewcustom cellForRowAtIndexPath];
    
    
    
}`

Comment: The action needs to be in your view controller subclass. And (id)sender needs to be (UIButton *)sender

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `UITableViewCell` and add a touple property to it. key containing the `index.row` and value containing the URL eg:- 1:"www.stackoverflow.com". When you click on a button, all you have to figure out is the `index.row` and from that you can get the value that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can add target for button in cellForRowAtIndexPath like :

```
 [cell.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

here you can receive the action for this button

```
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInView:self.tblview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblview  indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPos];
if(indexPath != nil){

// handle click event..
    }
}
```

surely it will work.........